# Java Xpath query failing on compile

Tags: java, xml, xpath, sax

I have the following XML document:

```
<application xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/app-config/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schemas/app-config/1.0   http://www.example.com/schemas/app-config/1.0/app-config-1.0.xsd">
    <info name="Dummy Application" runningOn="Dev"/>
</application>
```

When I run the following code:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/application/info@name");
```

I get an `XPathExpressionException` on the `compile` method. The exception's message is simply "`null`". It looks like I'm correctly using XPath to locate the `name` attribute, but I'm wondering if all my XMLNS and XSI declarations are causing problems here? If not then I'm totally clueless and have no idea what's causing this exception.

One thing - how can `compile` be failing before I ever associate the `xpath` instance with my actual `Document` object?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a syntax error in the expression `/application/info@name`, the correct syntax is `/application/info/@name`. Note however that your XML sample has a default namespace so with XPath 1.0 the expression `/application/info/@name` does not select anything in that sample, with XPath 2.0 you would need to make sure you associate define the default namespace for the XPath evaluation. With XPath 1.0 you need to define a prefix (e.g. `df`) for the default namespace in your Java code and then use e.g. `/df:application/df:info/@name`. I am not familiar with the Java XPath API so someone else needs to help with concrete code on how to set up the namespaces with an XPathNamespaceContext or similar.

Answer (score 2):

The compile method throws an exception because your XPath expression is invalid. You probably want to use `"/application/info/@name"`.